# clear_fig not working on one tab after another tab is used

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, tkinter, plot

I have a GUI with multiple tabs, I use tabs 2 and 3. First I coded tab 2 - a figure that takes a plot when a plot data button is pressed, and clears when a clear button is pressed, this worked fine.
But when I coded a second tab with similar functionality - yet with a totally different plot - the clear plot/clear fig works on that second tab yet not the first.
The clear plot buttons are linked to different clear_fig functions with different names.

I can post the complete code but it's large and I don't want to get kicked off here for adding it, I also don't know how to minimise it into the lowest reproducible error.

***Code***

**Tab2 function**

```
def clearPlot():
    fig.clear()
    my_canvas.draw_idle()

button3 = tk.Button(my_frame_2, text = "Clear \nPlot", command = clearPlot, relief = tk.GROOVE, bg = "red", padx =20, pady =20 )
button3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

**Tab3 function**

```
def clearPlotOPW():
    fig2.clear()
    my_canvas.draw_idle()

button2_opw = tk.Button(my_frame_4, text = "Clear \nPlot", command = clearPlotOPW, relief = tk.GROOVE, bg = "red", padx =20, pady =20 )
button2_opw.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Comment: why dont you just pass the fig object into the function and have 1 function rather than 2?

Comment: @GhandiFloss - how do you do that? The GUI is likely to have 8 tabs by the end of it, i'm not sure how to do that passing of a fig as an argument to the clearPlot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments you could change your function to take in a fig. Maybe also use `partial`

```
from functools import partial

def clearPlot(fig):
    fig.clear()

# pass in the fig you want clearing here
funcArgs = partial(clearPlot, figureX)
button = Tk.Button(master=frame, text='Clear', command=funcArgs)
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work for me, updated the command in the button to call the functionalists to clear and passed fig into it. If I totally delete the code for the third tab my previous code clearing button&func for tab2 works fine.